# How do I unignore a message in Facebook Messenger?

Tags: facebook-messenger

I have ignored someone on Messenger, and want to undo this without actually sending them a message. When I open their conversation from Filtered Messages in the browser version of Facebook, there is no Reply/Delete option. When opening the conversation in the Messenger App, it only gives me one option: "I don't want to hear from [name]"

If I encounter this scenario, how do I undo an ignore?

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't seem to be possible unless you reply to the user you ignored. According to [WikiHow](https://www.wikihow.com/Unignore-Someone-on-Messenger):

> The only way to unignore someone on Messenger is to reply to the conversation in the Spam folder. Unfortunately, there's no way to unignore without replying in any version of Messenger.

It used to be possible [using the Messenger Lite Android app](https://webtrickz.com/unignore-messages-messenger-without-replying/), but that's been discontinued and removed from the Play Store.

Answer (score 0):

I went onto a computer,  went into messages, searched for the person. Far right of the screen by their picture is a settings button  click unblock messages. [image]

Comment: This seems to be the answer for when someone is "blocked", which is different from "ignoring" someone.